# We share iCloud accounts on two devices, can both backup photos to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

Can 2 devices back up each one's photos with same iCloud account into iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, iCloud backup will keep the backups of your Camera Roll separate.

If you mean Photo Stream, yes, the photos will be merged into a single Photo Stream.